# Qt GUI programming query

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, oop

Im currently developing a GUI application using the Qt framework. The application is a basic "2D CAD" like interface with less complexities of a commercial 2D CAD software.

The idea is, there is a tool box (like MS paint) which contains rectangle and square shapes of various sizes (The purpose of this GUI is to design RC circuit design on flexible substrates. This software will generate G-codes (basically coordinate information for a CNC machine) which will be fed to a CNC printer which prints these circuits on flexible substrates based on the G-code information generated). Each rectangle/square shape contains gcode for their 'shape' in a text file in a known directory (lets say this is text file ORIGINAL). These G-codes in the text files are based on for shapes drawn from the origin of the coordinate system of the GUI. When the user clicks on a specific square/rectangle, a movable/draggable shape appears on "origin" of  the QtGraphicsView widget and this action automatically creates a new text file in a known directory which copies all the G-codes from the text file (from ORIGINAL text file) containing the original G-codes for this specific shape drawn at origin (lets say this text file CLONE).  Since these shapes are movable, when the user drags/moves a specific  item on the screen, the software should be able to access the CLONE file it created for this specific item and edit/offset the coordinates copied from the ORIGINAL for this specific shape by the current coordinate position of the shape.

For example when the user first clicks a shape and the shape appears on the origin of the QtGraphicsView widget, this will create a CLONE for this item containing a the coordinate/G-codes for this shape from the ORIGINAL for this shape. Then the user moves the item to (100,-65). So this action of the user offsets each coordinate information of the CLONE created before by the new coordinates (100,-65) and saves the CLONE text file. Further more, lets say the user adds the same 'shape' from the toolbox again, which results in the same 'shape' appearing on the QtGraphicsView widget's origin. In this case there are two duplicates of the same 'shape' on the QtGraphicsView widget. When this second action happens the GUI should generate a new CLONE file for this duplicate of the same shape and should execute editing/offsetting coordinates of this CLONE when the corresponding duplicate of the shape is moved/dragged.  Likewise, when a specific item is deleted from the QtGraphicsView widget, the corresponding CLONE of the item should be deleted from the directory as well. Moreover the GUI should be able to generate CLONES for multiple shapes provided on the toolbox based on their specific ORIGINAL files.

Having said the idea, I have currently created the layout for the GUI with its toolbox and QtGraphicsView widget. Im able to access the ORIGINAL files for various shapes and create respective CLONES for each item on the added on the QtGraphicsView widget. The challenge I face here is I'm unable to code/programme the following actions,

1) Whenever a duplicate of an item which is already present on the screen is added again, Im not able to create a specific CLONE for this item. The following is the code for when one such item is clicked/added from the toolbox to the QtGraphicsView widget.

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_3_clicked()

{
    //32 Ohms resitance (base square resistor)

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    QBrush blackBrush(Qt::darkGray);
    QPen outlinePen(Qt::black);
    outlinePen.setWidth(2);

    rect = scene->addRect(-100,-100,20,20,outlinePen,blackBrush);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    text = scene->addText("32Ohms");
    text->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    text->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

    QFile file_in("/Users/vinokanthvelu/Desktop/Graphite Circuitry printer/GUI/Gcodes/32_ohm_in.rtf");
    QFile file_out("/Users/vinokanthvelu/Desktop/Graphite Circuitry printer/GUI/Gcodes/output.txt");

    if(file_in.exists() == true)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Found","File exists");
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","Not found");
    }

    if(!file_in.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","file_in ERROR");
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(&file_in);
    while(!file_in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readAll();
        if(!file_out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text))
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","file_out ERROR");
            return;
        }
        QTextStream out(&file_out);

        //Copy the gcodes from the source file to output file
        out << line << endl;
    }
}
```

This is because when a duplicate is created, this actions tries to create a CLONE with same name as the CLONE of the previous duplicate of the same item. Which is not whats required.

2) How do I create IDs for CLONES of each of the duplicates of the same shape added to the QtGraphicsView widget? This is important because when the duplicate of a specific shape is moved/fragged/deleted, the ID for that specific duplicate is used to access the corresponding CLONE.

3) Other than my idea of creating CLONES for various duplicates of several shapes to keep track of coordinate positions of all items on the QtGraphicsView widget from corresponding ORIGINALS, is there any other efficient way to achieve this?

Sorry for the long post. I wanted to deliver a clear detailed question so its easier to grasp and address the problem (Im a newbie to Qt and object oriented programming).

Comment: In addition to this, I believe (Im maybe wrong) that real solution to this problem creating an ID for each item/shape is to create an event for each selection of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing files in a blocking fashion as a direct result of an action on a drawing canvas is generally a bad idea. The user experience will be very bad.

You should preload all the predefined shapes in a background thread on program startup, and then maintain them as data structures. You should only save the cloned shapes when the user wants to save the data, or automatically, but it should be done in a separate thread as well, with proper short-term locking. The file writer should lock only long enough to make a copy of the data, and then release the lock before performing any file access.

This then makes the ID generation trivial: you can generate a unique sequential ID as you're writing the shapes to disk. I also question the necessity of writing all the cloned shapes into individual files. Ideally, if your printer supports it, you should write all used shapes only once as RS-274X macros, and then instantiate the macros for each clone. This will minimize the size of the output file, and make it retain some of the structure of the original design. RS-274X might be sufficient as your only design file format.

Comment: Hello kuba Ober, thank you for your answer. Actually I'm really unable to understand your answer (I don't get the idea why I need threads to achieve this). It would be great if you can provide me a detailed explanation of your answer. Thank you and cheers.

Comment: @VinokanthVelu Blocking file access can take an arbitrary amount of time. While your application is waiting for the filesystem to respond, the GUI is blocked. The only portable way of dealing with blocking file access is to perform it from a thread other than the GUI thread.